# ArrayList stores only the last value read

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to read contacts from my android phone to modify them and write them back into the database.
 The  project has three classes so far:

- The MainActivity.java. This is where I read the database, populate the contacts objects I've created and the put them in a list.

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

  // Store contacts values in these arraylist.
  // I t is not really needed for this implementation but I keep this just in case

  public static ArrayList<String> phoneValueArr = new ArrayList<>();
  public static ArrayList<String> nameValueArr = new ArrayList<>();

  // Store the values of names and associated phone numbers.
  public  ContactData contactsData= new ContactData(); 

  // List to store the contacts
  public  ContactsDataList contactsList= new ContactsDataList();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
  (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<String>());
  readContactsData();

  //Display the number of contacts
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
          "read " + phoneValueArr.size() + " contacts. "  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


  pressButton();

      for(ContactData c:contactsList.getContacts()){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  c.getContact_name() + "Hopes   on God "  ,    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }

  }
  }

  public  void readContactsData() {

  try {

      // Reading Contacts Name And Number

      String phoneNumber = "";
      ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();

      // Query to get contact name

      Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
              null, null, null);

      // If data data found in contacts
      if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

       Log.i("AutocompleteContacts", "Reading   contacts........");

       int k = 0;
       String name = "";

       //Until there are no more contacts stored
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        String id = cur.getString(cur
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        name = cur
        .getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

              // Check contact have phone number
              if (Integer
                      .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                              .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                  // Create query to get phone number by contact id
                  Cursor pCur = cr
                  .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                  null,
                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                  + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                  null);
                  int j = 0;

                  //Until query is stopped
                  while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                      // Sometimes get multiple data
                      if (j == 0) {
                          // Get Phone number
                          phoneNumber = ""
                                  + pCur.getString(pCur
                                          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                          // Add contacts names to adapter
                          adapter.add(name);

                          // Add ArrayList names to adapter
                          phoneValueArr.add(phoneNumber.toString());
                          nameValueArr.add(name.toString());

                          // Set contact name and phone number
                          // i.e parse the SQLlite query to set the POJO's
                          contactsData.setPhone_number(phoneNumber.toString());
                          contactsData.setContact_name(name.toString());


                          // Add Contacts to list
                          contactsList.addContact(contactsData);


                        j++;
                          k++;
                      }

                  } // End while loop

                  pCur.close();
              } // End if

          }// End while loop

      } // End Cursor value check
      cur.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.i("AutocompleteContacts", "Exception : " + e);
  }
  }
  ```
- The ContactData class where I create the class from which the objects are instantiated.

  ```
  public class ContactData {

  public String contact_name;
  public String phone_number;

  public ContactData(){

  }

  public  ContactData(String contact_name, String phone_number) {

  this.contact_name=contact_name;
  this.phone_number=phone_number;
  }



  public String getContact_name() {
  return contact_name;
  }

  public void setContact_name(String contact_name) {
  this.contact_name = contact_name;
  }
  public String getPhone_number() {
  return phone_number;
  }
  public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
  this.phone_number = phone_number;
  }

   public String toString() {
      return contact_name + ", " + phone_number;
  }


  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof ContactData) {
      ContactData contact = (ContactData) obj;
      return (contact_name.equals(contact.getContact_name()) && phone_number
              .equals(contact.getPhone_number()));
  }

  return false;
  }


  public int hashCode() {
      return (contact_name.length() + phone_number.length());
  }
   class ContactNameComparator implements Comparator<ContactData> {
      public int compare(ContactData contact1, ContactData contact2) {
          return   contact1.getContact_name().compareToIgnoreCase(contact2.getContact_name());
      }
   }
   }
  ```
- The ContactsDataList which takes the objects and stores them.

  ```
   public class ContactsDataList  {



   public List<ContactData> contactList;

  public ContactsDataList() {

  this(new ArrayList<ContactData>());
  }

  public ContactsDataList(List<ContactData> contactList) {
  this.contactList = contactList;
  }

  public void addContact(ContactData contact) {
  if (contactList != null) {
          contactList.add(contact);
      }
  }

  public List<ContactData> getContacts() {
  return contactList;
  }

  public void setContacts(List<ContactData> contacts) {
  this.contactList = contacts;
  }


  }
  ```

The Contact objects that I have in my list are all the same and I don't see where I went wrong as the arraylists phoneValuerArr and nameValueArr all have the correct data.

The ContactsDataList, contactList, only contains the last contact read.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reusing the same instance of `ContactData` in every iteration of the `while` loop but just updating its properties.  You need to create a separate instance per iteration

```
while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
    ...
    ContactData contactsData = new ContactData();
    contactsData.setPhoneNumber(...);
    ...
}
```